# Leviton usb charger into an old handy work box

Tags: electrical

The dimensions what is stated for the receptacle is 3"x2"x2-1/2" (they state standard single gang electrical wall box). However i have an old handy end run work box that is 3-1/2" x 1 3/4" to the metal screws which is the end of the depth.  When I measure the depth of the usb it truly measures 1-3/4" totally. However from their metal screw holders on both end of the usb it is 1 1/4" to the end of their receptacle and to their front from the metal holders it is 1/2".  After screwing it in the handy box it protrude only 3/16 from the wall plate not 1/2". Is 3/16 acceptable to NEC standards though they never defined 'flush or thereof'. I know it is suppose to be flush or an 1/8 example gfci to protrude? And how could leviton say it is 2 1/2" depth which it isnt? And finally is there a way that if i decide to keep my old handy metal box to reduce that protrusion by a 1/16 or so? Will do whatever to be in conformity?

---

[image: usb charger that is 3/16]. Im sorry for making this a big deal but if your playing with electricity it should be clearly spelled out.

Comment: why not add an extender ring? jamming stuff into a box to the back is not a good idea in general. 2 1/2 is what they think the unit needs. it may overheat if there is not enough space.

Comment: @bib your right. Extinction metal rings works but isnt easier to just get a deeper box since i still have to disconnect the box and add an extension ring box to connect it to the handy box to make it larger? Also thank you. Also with my second part can you protrude 3/16?. There enough with a 1/2 inch in the back and plenty side space in my opinion. They told me on the phone as long as it fits in a single gang box?

Answer (score 3):

To start, all devices should be mounted flush into the wall unless they are designed otherwise. This is to prevent fire and shock hazard. Leviton and other devices are giving you a box size not only to fit the device but provide air space for heat disbursement.

NEC Article 314 has instructions on how many devices by cubic inch, wire splices, and number and size of conductors you can put into one box. I would follow that rather than instructions in a box or someone who would say it it fits it's ok.

Is there any way you could remove the box and install a cut-in or remodel box that is a required size? If I could that's how I would go.

Comment: Regardless if a get a cut in or a deeper box, the design of this USB will make a protrusion and would qualify as a design otherwise. Again NEC did say flush but also flush thereof without any limits on protrusion technically.  Only have two wires --en run conduit. . Regardless of any size box it will protrude (like gfci). Leviton didnt have an answer either? Regardless thank you. Larry

Comment: Im probably making more than what is but the NEC IS STILL NOT CLEAR WHEN IT SAYS FLUSH OR THEREOF. Define thereof...see attached picture. I just want anyone know what the limit of a protrusion should be.

Answer (score 3):

The protrusion is not a Code issue whatsoever as long as no live parts are accessible due to it -- NEC 406.5(D) simply says that the receptacle can't recess behind the faceplate.  (If it did, then the box/faceplate would no longer meet the NEMA 1 or equivalent IP20 enclosure protection requirements.)

> **(D) Position of Receptacle Faces.** After installation, receptacle faces shall be flush with or project from faceplates
>   of insulating material and shall project a minimum of
>   0.4 mm (0.015 in.) from metal faceplates.

As to box depth?  If it fits and does not violate the box fill rules, and the conductors aren't kinked, crushed, or crimped as that wouldn't be "neat and workmanlike" to do, I'd say it's fine.

Comment: Thanks Ed, that was the answer i was looking for.  Wasnt trying to cause issues just wanted clarity. Thank you again.